# What is the purpose of rustc-std-workspace-core crate?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

Looking at some crates in https://crates.io/ I found that `rand` is the most downloaded crate and looking in it's dependencies I found the `libc` crate and in it's dependencies I found the [rustc-std-workspace-core](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-std-workspace-core/1.0.0) which has 0 dependencies
with this description: "Explicitly empty crate for rust-lang/rust integration". I could not totally undestand what it means. Can someone explain in more details?

Comment: The [README](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/rustc-std-workspace-core/README.md) file for the crate in the Rust repo provides a bit of additional context: _"Crates on crates.io that the standard library depend on need to depend on the rustc-std-workspace-core crate from crates.io, which is empty. We use [patch] to override it to this crate in this repository. As a result, crates on crates.io will draw a dependency edge to libcore, the version defined in this repository. That should draw all the dependency edges to ensure Cargo builds crates successfully!"_

Comment: "This crate is a shim and empty crate which simply depends on libcore and reexports all of its contents" what is this libcore? I couldn't find any crate with this name

Comment: `libcore`, or `core`, is the name of the crate that includes everything that is essential for Rust code and some more, and doesn't require an Operating System. It is like `std` but more primitive.

Comment: But why can't I find then in crates.io?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco You can't find what?

Comment: The `libcore` and `core` crates. If you search for them in crates.io it will not return them.
https://crates.io/search?q=libcore
https://crates.io/search?q=core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std` depends on the `libc` crate.

Being a dependency of `std` is... not easy. The way `std` is built is complicated, it is tightly coupled with the compiler and built with it *twice*, for bootstrapping.

[You can see this dependency is only activated if the `rustc-dep-of-std` feature is enabled](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/blob/99756b1a974d293a3c61d13f5cf4affe6d0998fc/Cargo.toml#L28).

This dependency allows `std` to depend on crates.

See also [Plan for removal of `rustc-dep-of-std`](https://github.com/rust-lang/wg-cargo-std-aware/issues/51).

Comment: By `std` you mean the standard library? Sorry, I'm a newbie in rust

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Yes, that is a common shortcut and also the name of the crate (`use std::xxx;`).